# Value error when converting string to float

Tags: python, matplotlib, file-handling

it is showing value error for converting string into float.
one of the line of my data file looks like this
`100   1.2811559340137890E-003`
I think maybe python can't understand E while converting. also following is my code

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = []
y = []
f= open('C:/Users/Dell/assignment2/error_n.dat', 'r')
for line in f:
    line= line.split(' ')

    x.append(line[0])
    y.append(line[1])
for i in range(0,4):
    x[i]=float(x[i])
    x[i]=math.log(x[i])
    y[i]=float(y[i])
    y[i]=math.log(y[i])
        

plt.plot(y, x, marker = 'o', c = 'g')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Always show us the *full traceback message* - it will indicate the exact string value that failed to be converted to a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `1.2811559340137890E-003` can be converted to `float` without a problem. You can easily try this in the Python shell:

```
>>> s = '1.2811559340137890E-003'
>>> float(s)
0.001281155934013789
```

However, you're actually trying to convert an empty string. See why:

```
>>> line = '100   1.2811559340137890E-003'
>>> line.split(' ')
['100', '', '', '1.2811559340137890E-003']
```

To solve your problem, simply change `line.split(' ')` to `line.split()`:

```
>>> line.split()
['100', '1.2811559340137890E-003']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when you split that line, the second item (y) is `""` (an empty string), and that's the one which can't be converted into a number.

Answer (score 0):

`float` is able to handle scientific notations. However from your description, it seems like the `ValueError` was thrown from trying to convert empty string to float.

```
'100   1.2811559340137890E-003'.split(' ')
```

will return

```
['100', '', '', '1.2811559340137890E-003']
```

You can check the string before converting it to float to handle such error.